# Not able to access network share path of on-premise server from Azure database migration service

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, smb, file-sharing

I am using Azure database migration service for SQL Db migration from ON-premise SQL server to Azure SQL managed instance. While making configuration setting am getting the error "Not able to authenticate to network file share path" . AS the windows user credential I have provided has Read\Write access to the same path. Also the TCP ports 135 & 445 are opened.
Can anyone suggest me the way?

Comment: Which way did you use，offline or online?

Comment: Online Migration